# Connect a socket to another PC in same NAT

Tags: ip, nat, tcp, c#, sockets

Hey I've got two machines on the same network. They get their IP info back from an external webserver. Same IP due to NAT but different ports locally. Hmm that's weird.. they can't socket up or even see each other. Example:

```
Microsoft Telnet> open 1.129.108.250 16054
Connecting To 1.129.108.250...Could not open connection to the host, on port 16054: Connect failed

C:\Users\Andrew>ping 1.129.108.250

Pinging 1.129.108.250 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
    
Ping statistics for 1.129.108.250:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Idk. Is there like an 'external port' to worry about, because of NAT? I mean I start a listener on port 10000, will it still be 10000 to someone else? Even the case, why can't they ping? They're both in my bedroom on same network. Thanks

EDIT:

To explain it better, both machines get their external IP address from my web server, and it's 1.129.108.250 on each. So the port will differentiate. But they seem to not think of each other as being on the same network except by virtue of running on my wifi. It's hotspotted from mobile as if it makes any difference. Also, what would happen if they choose the same port to listen?  Will NAT crash or malfunction?

EDIT 2:

How many combinations are there in practice?

```
PC1 in NAT      PC2 in NAT  (same network)
PC1 in NAT      PC2 in NAT  (different networks)
PC1 not in NAT  PC2 in NAT  (different networks)
```

Is it true to say that anyone *outside* the network doesn't need special logic? Since the routers take care to make everything look normal. I guess this is one thing user1686 meant.

If 1.2.3.4:1000 actually maps to 192.168.0.1:10000 then it must behave just like a real endpoint..

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement hole punching? Why not use ready-made solutions?

Comment: Slightly related but very good article: https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes it is exactly what I want to do. This is hard, since I'm not a network engineer, just developer. NAT seems to be a huge pain in the ass. And I could go on for days about how TCP was poorly designed. Maybe I could use a 3rd party middleware as you suggested, but I always prefer my own code since other guys make lots of bugs sometimes. Anyway let's see...

Comment: Why do you think you're not going to introduce any bugs? You're just learning about networking, while the other guys have spent years implementing this stuff for hundreds of thousands of actual users who rely on this every day.

Comment: An endpoint is the combination of [ip address, port number]. My app can listen on 1.2.3.4:10000 but if the NAT changes it to 33.62.123.0:12345, how can i know what the real endpoint is? I can get the IP by asking my website. But how to find out what port I'm actually listening on? It's kinda hard and makes me think NAT wasn't designed well. I think the case for local IP is solved now but external is an open question...

Comment: If there is something like this, but like 'Socket.LocalEndpointFromOutside' it would be perfect. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.localendpoint?view=net-5.0.  Btw I read your article, its good and has lots of info. But if I need to set a relay it would slow things down bigtime..

Comment: bro.. i used to write software for investment banks to send orders into tokyo, chicago, new york, london. so, it's a little stretch to call me a learner :)

Answer (score 1):

> They get their IP info back from an external webserver. Same IP due to NAT but different ports locally.

The *port* reported by the webserver doesn't mean much. Each new TCP connection gets a completely new local port assigned by the client – even from a single machine without any NAT, the web server would keep seeing different ports every time you hit F5. (Some NATs preserve the ports, others always translate them.)

> Hmm that's weird.. they can't socket up or even see each other. Example:

This is not a "listening" port – it isn't accepting new connections; it was only allocated as the source port for a specific *outbound* connection, and you cannot `telnet` into it (even if NAT weren't a concern).

> Even the case, why can't they ping?

The *address* reported by the webserver doesn't belong to any of your machines. When behind NAT, the "external" IP address belongs *only* to the router that's performing NAT (typically yours, but in case of CGNAT it's one at the ISP). So when you're pinging your external IP address, you're *always* pinging just the router – not any machine behind it.

Most "home" routers are configured to ignore all ping requests to their external address.

> Also, what would happen if they choose the same port to listen? Will NAT crash or malfunction?

No, the NAT will just rewrite the ports to not conflict. (All "1:many" NATs have to keep track of every connection in order to un-NAT the inbound responses; the same state table tells them whether there's another connection using this local port.)

Some NATs just always rewrite the source port for every connection, even if there's no conflict.

> It's hotspotted from mobile as if it makes any difference

It does. It's very possible that the phone applies "client isolation" for its hotspots and tethering – if that's the case, two devices connected to the same hotspot won't be able to contact each other even using their "private" IP addresses, despite everything seeming like they should be able to. (My Android phone doesn't seem to isolate Wi-Fi hotspot clients, but it does put a wall between Wi-Fi and USB tethering.)

> How many combinations are there in practice?

**Many.** A host could be behind a local NAT, or behind *two* local NATs (or three!), or behind ISP-managed CGNAT, or behind two local NATs *and* CGNAT. (Or no NAT at all, of course.)

Each of those NAT layers could be "cone NAT" or "symmetric" – weird names aside, one allocates a mapping usable by all remote endpoints, the other does not. (In a peer-to-peer situation, automated hole-punching is possible in many cases, but not when both peers are behind symmetric-type NATs.)

See the article by Tailscale on [how NAT traversal works](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works/) to see just a few possibilities.

> Is it true to say that anyone outside the network doesn't need special logic?

Only if your connections are strictly from inside *to* outside (e.g. browser making a HTTP connection to a public web server).

> My app can listen on 1.2.3.4:10000 but if the NAT changes it to 33.62.123.0:12345, how can i know what the real endpoint is? I can get the IP by asking my website. But how to find out what port I'm actually listening on?

You aren't. There *isn't* any external port that you're assigned. Outbound connections get *temporary* NAT mappings assigned whenever the NATing router sees packets go through (and it only lasts as long as that connection); for listening sockets, there won't be any mapping unless someone adds one manually.

If you're lucky, the nearest NAT might be accepting either NAT-PMP (now PCP) or UPnP IGD requests to establish a persistent mapping that allows inbound connections; this is common in e.g. BitTorrent clients. You tell the router your listener's local address:port, and the router's response will have the external address *and* port that was assigned.

If not... well, you get into the "NAT traversal" territory.

> NAT seems to be a huge pain in the ass. And I could go on for days about how TCP was poorly designed.

'Fortunately', NAT isn't actually part of TCP. It's a "short-term bandaid" that got bodged on top of TCP/IP two decades ago and we've been living with it since.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer...

NAT is used to aggregate multiple machines into a single network connection to make them appear as one machine on an external network.  In that process, NAT rewrites internal internal-ip:port addresses into a temporary unique external-ip:port address.  As such, the internal and external ports are unrelated, and incoming connections from the external network are typically blocked.

If you start a listener on an internal machine, an external machine will not be able to connect to it through the NAT unless you have specifically configured the NAT to permanently map the port and pass external traffic to that port on that machine.

If you want two machines on the inside network to talk to each other, they must use their internal unique ip addresses, not the shared external ip address.

Comment: Thanks but, why would a port mapping be needed? I'm currently behind NAT afaik, but apps like torrent and chatting all work without some special port setting.

Comment: Port mapping is what a NAT does.   The NAT is designed to allow outgoing connections while blocking incoming connections.  The chat is probably using an outgoing TCP connection. There are special algorithms in use for UDP ports so that something like an internal torrent server opens the external port by sending packets out.  (UDP is connectionless as far as the router knows, so blocking an external udp "connection" doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Thanks, I want to use TCP too. But it's like an introduction where you don't know your own name..

Comment: Unless you are running local servers, NAT doesn't prevent TCP use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. Looks like I need to do something like this:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18492/STUN-Client

Also, to write my own S.T.U.N. service because I don't want to rely on another server that could go down anytime.

Comment: By its very nature, STUN servers need to be external, outside your NAT.

Comment: Ah I meant make a STUN and host it on my own server. But it must use a different approach. Getting requests over HTTP doesn't let me see their port, so far as I can see...